# Deploying OpenStack with just two machines with Juju

Tags: juju

i've followed the Marco Ceppi guide (http://marcoceppi.com/2014/06/deploying-openstack-with-just-two-machines/comment-page-1/#comment-70358) about how to deploy openstack on just 2 node.
I tried to re-create that on a virtual environment using KVM as hypervisor and 4 vnode both of them on the same vnet. On these node I've installed the environment in this way:

- vnode 0 juju-gui
- vnode 1 mysql,keystone,nova-cloud-controller,glance,rabbitmq-server,openstack- 
  dashboard,cinder
- vnode 2 nova-compute

all nodes are Deployed and run perfectly, juju idem. The all relations are made and in green status,all service are explose.

[image]

Horizon has worked just one time, after the reboot of all nodes if I try to open Horizon receive this error

"This webpage is not available"

[image]

I've also tried to restart apache on node but nothing. As Marco requested me here the pastebin of this file

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9441299/ 
and 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9441304/

Comment: anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of `sudo initclt list` and `ps -aef` from the horizon node and edit your question to include this new content.

Comment: as your requested I've added that output

Comment: Can you run the following and then check if horizon is working?

`sudo a2ensite horizon` and
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: the result of the command is not good http://paste.ubuntu.com/9457273/ horizon does not exit!!! why?

Comment: What machine are you on? did you `juju ssh openstack-dashboard/0` or did you SSH directly to the physical machine?

Comment: Actually, I think I already know the answer to that. When you were doing the deployments, did you run all the services that are on node1 with `--to lxc:...` ?

Comment: I used the command juju ssh openstack-dashboard/0 on vnode where I've installed MaaS and the connection is worked, then from physical machine I ping to vnodes using thier own FQDN and the host resolution worked. On first lab I've used lxc as reported from your guide excluded juju-gui and compute-node. While on second lab I've not used lxc and in both case the result is always the same, Horizon is down.